# Will upgrading from an old wireless router to a newer improve speed at my house?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Our internet connection is not the fastest. It's not super slow either. Used primarily for browsing the internet, SOME videos, very few downloads or trrents, etc. Wireless range somewhat sucks at the moment, so that would be nice if it improved.

So, assuming all things are equal and the only switch is the router...
Would it be faster (for both ethernet-connected computers AND wireless laptops) if I upgraded from a Netgear WPN824 RangeMax to an Asus Black Diamond?

Or would it be very close to the same? I only want to shell out the 130 bucks if it will be a noticeable improvement.

I use the Black Diamond at work and like it, so that's why I use it for an example.

Answer (score 3):

In all likelihood no.

The limitation is **almost always** imposed by the ISP (as seen when you upgrade your service, you pay a bit more, they click a few buttons and you have faster internet).

The wireless range however *may* improve, the Netgear looks pretty old and newer routers usually perform better. But it *does* somewhat depend on your house/apartment. Lots of stone and metal will degrade performance (lots of neighbours with wifi will do the same).

Comment: +1 - 99.999% of the time your wireless router isn't the bottleneck. You can try boosting your signal to non-kosher ranges by installing a custom firmware to your router, but this is an **advanced** procedure and if something goes wrong you can brick your router.

Answer (score 1):

Run a speed test using a wired connection to your wireless router, suggest dslreports or similar.

The result here is your theoretical maximum performance.

Repeat test using wifi.

If results are similar, the router upgrade will not make a bit of difference.